# I have an error with cv2 in python,I uninstall it and install it again but I still have the same error

Tags: python, opencv

the error is :

cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.4) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:1257: error: (-2:Unspecified error) The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x
or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvNamedWindow'

Comment: "The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Cocoa support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script in function 'cvNamedWindow'"—this seems pretty clear to me. How did you install `cv2`? On what operating system?

Comment: I just paste this comment in the terminal pip install opencv-python

Comment: I'm using visual studio code -python

Comment: I asked what _operating system_ you are using.

Comment: i am using windows

Comment: you installed the `headless` OpenCV package. remove that package. install a package that isn't headless. install exactly one opencv package, not multiple. -- and since you're new, please take the [tour] and review [ask]. you're expected to **search** for the error and only ask if you didn't find an answer.